# Is is possible to add Perspectives in MDG technologies?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to have a given perspective in a MDG technology, however, when I generate the technology I see no such option.

[image]

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that isn't possible.

Perspective's manage which MDG's are enabled and which aren't.

Storing a perspective in an MDG seems a bit the wrong way round.

But if you have a good case, you can certainly send in a [feature request](https://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/feature_request.html)